# Distribution and Standard deviation

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

> Let $X$ be normally distributed with a mean of $105$ and standard deviation
> of $10$.
>
> 1. What is the probability that $X > 112$?
> 2. What value of $X$ does only the top $5\%$ exceed ?

Comment: This is a standard exercise on Gaussian distribution. What did you try?

Comment: Not sure how to do this question

Comment: I gave you some hints in my answer...can you conclude now? Please show your efforts amending you original post

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure how to do this question

ok.

Using standardization that is

$$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$$

you can use Z-score to calculate probablities...

thus

$$P(X<112)=P\left(Z<\frac{112-105}{10}\right)$$

and obviously

$$P(X>112)=1-P(X<112)$$

---

The second question is an inverse Z-score problem...they give you the probability and you have to calculate the quantile

Comment: just trying it now thanks for your help